# Adjust Adwords bid-to-position script to apply to specific ad groups

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I'm trying to edit the Google AdWords Bid-To-Position script so it will adjust keyword bids for ad groups of my choosing.  Right now I'm trying to use an ad group id in an array, assign it to the variable "campaignSelector", and then get the keywords for that variable.  Below is what I have so far.  For whatever reason, I keep getting the error - TypeError: Cannot find function keywords in object [AdGroupSelector]. (line 24).  Can anyone help?

```js
// Ad position you are trying to achieve.
var TARGET_AVERAGE_POSITION = 3;

// Once the keywords fall within TOLERANCE of TARGET_AVERAGE_POSITION,
// their bids will no longer be adjusted.
var TOLERANCE = 0.1;

// How much to adjust the bids.
var BID_ADJUSTMENT_COEFFICIENT = 1.05;

function main() {
  raiseKeywordBids();
  lowerKeywordBids();
}

function raiseKeywordBids() {
  // Condition to raise bid: Average position is greater (worse) than
  // target + tolerance
  var ids = [2123818938];
  var campaignSelector = AdWordsApp.adGroups().withIds(ids);


  var keywordsToRaise = campaignSelector.keywords()
    .withCondition("Status = ENABLED")
    .withCondition("AveragePosition > " + (TARGET_AVERAGE_POSITION + TOLERANCE))
    .orderBy("AveragePosition ASC")
    .forDateRange("LAST_7_DAYS")
    .get();

  while (keywordsToRaise.hasNext()) {
    var keyword = keywordsToRaise.next();
    keyword.setMaxCpc(keyword.getMaxCpc() * BID_ADJUSTMENT_COEFFICIENT);
  }
}

function lowerKeywordBids() {
  // Conditions to lower bid: Ctr greater than 1% AND
  // average position better (less) than target - tolerance
  var ids = [2123818938];
  var campaignSelector = AdWordsApp.adGroups().withIds(ids);

  var keywordsToLower = campaignSelector.keywords()
    .withCondition("Ctr > 0.01")
    .withCondition("AveragePosition < " + (TARGET_AVERAGE_POSITION - TOLERANCE))
    .withCondition("Status = ENABLED")
    .orderBy("AveragePosition DESC")
    .forDateRange("LAST_7_DAYS")
    .get();


  while (keywordsToLower.hasNext()) {
    var keyword = keywordsToLower.next();
    keyword.setMaxCpc(keyword.getMaxCpc() / BID_ADJUSTMENT_COEFFICIENT);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Ad position you are trying to achieve.
var TARGET_AVERAGE_POSITION = 1;

// Once the keywords fall within TOLERANCE of TARGET_AVERAGE_POSITION,
// their bids will no longer be adjusted.
var TOLERANCE = 0.1;

// How much to adjust the bids.
var BID_ADJUSTMENT_COEFFICIENT = 1.05;

function main() {
  raiseKeywordBids();
  lowerKeywordBids();
}

function raiseKeywordBids() {
  // Condition to raise bid: Average position is greater (worse) than
  // target + tolerance
  var ids = [];
  var AdGroupSelector = AdWordsApp.adGroups().withIds(ids);

  var adGroupIterator = AdGroupSelector.get();
  while (adGroupIterator.hasNext()) {
    var adGroup = adGroupIterator.next();

    var keywordsToRaise = adGroup.keywords()
      .withCondition("Status = ENABLED")
      .withCondition("AveragePosition > " + (TARGET_AVERAGE_POSITION + TOLERANCE))
      .orderBy("AveragePosition ASC")
      .forDateRange("LAST_7_DAYS")
      .get();

    while (keywordsToRaise.hasNext()) {
      var keyword = keywordsToRaise.next();
      keyword.setMaxCpc(keyword.getMaxCpc() * BID_ADJUSTMENT_COEFFICIENT);
    }
  }
}

function lowerKeywordBids() {
  // Conditions to lower bid: Ctr greater than 1% AND
  // average position better (less) than target - tolerance
  var ids = [];
  var AdGroupSelector = AdWordsApp.adGroups().withIds(ids);

  var adGroupIterator = AdGroupSelector.get();
  while (adGroupIterator.hasNext()) {
    var adGroup = adGroupIterator.next();

    var keywordsToLower = adGroup.keywords()
      .withCondition("Ctr > 0.01")
      .withCondition("AveragePosition < " + (TARGET_AVERAGE_POSITION - TOLERANCE))
      .withCondition("Status = ENABLED")
      .orderBy("AveragePosition DESC")
      .forDateRange("LAST_7_DAYS")
      .get();


    while (keywordsToLower.hasNext()) {
      var keyword = keywordsToLower.next();
      keyword.setMaxCpc(keyword.getMaxCpc() / BID_ADJUSTMENT_COEFFICIENT);
    }
  }
}
```